Return index of cell that contains match on two strings
I'm trying to find the index for a cell that contains two string matches. For example, I have a first name and last name. I need to find a cell that contains both of these names in it.
Possible combinations of names could be the following Jobs, Steve or Jobs II, Steve or Jobs, Steve Apple or Jobs Jr, Steve Apple. You get the drift.
I need to return the index of the first matching cell that contains both the first and last name.
Here is my attempt. My thought was to try and find a match with the last name first and then see if that match contains the first name also:
var firstName = 'Steve';
var lastName = 'Jobs';
var columnOfNamesArr = ['Participants','Wozniak, Steve','Gates, Bill','Cook, Tim','Jobs, Mark','Jobs, Steve Apple','Musk, Elon'];

var lastNameIndex = columnOfNamesArr.findIndex(s => s.indexOf(lastName) >= 0);
var nameIndex = columnOfNamesArr[lastNameIndex].findIndex(s => s.indexOf(firstName) >= 0);

I get the following error though on the line that starts var firstNameIndex...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
What am I doing wrong and is there a way to do this all in one search instead of two?
Edit: Adding more details around how columnOfNamesArr is created.
I pull in a column like this:



Participants




Wozniak, Steve


Gates, Bill


Cook, Tim


Jobs, Mark


Jobs, Steve Apple


Musk, Elon



and I put it into a variable like this:
columnArr = namesSht.getRange('A1:A'+ LastRow).getValues();

and then I flatten like this:
var columnOfNamesArr = columnArr.map(r => r[0]);

That's when I try to run the findIndex and includes
var nameIndex = columnOfNamesArr.findIndex(s => s.includes(lastName) && s.includes(firstName));

but I get the error code I mentioned above.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize. At that time, can you provide your expected value? By this, I would like to modify it.

In your showing script, columnOfNamesArr[lastNameIndex] is a string value. When you want to use findIndex, it is required to use an array. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. If you want to retrieve the first index of the array columnOfNamesArr when both firstName and lastName are included, how about the following modification?
Modified script:


var firstName = 'Steve';
var lastName = 'Jobs';
var columnOfNamesArr = ['Participants', 'Wozniak, Steve', 'Gates, Bill', 'Cook, Tim', 'Jobs, Mark', 'Jobs, Steve Apple', 'Musk, Elon'];

// var index = columnOfNamesArr.findIndex(s => s.indexOf(lastName) >= 0 && s.indexOf(firstName) >= 0);
var index = columnOfNamesArr.findIndex(s => s.includes(lastName) && s.includes(firstName));

console.log(index);
console.log({ value: columnOfNamesArr[index] });



When this script is run, 5 is shown in the log.
Note:

If both firstName and lastName are included in the inputed array and you want to retrieve the indexes as an array, how about the following modification?
var firstName = 'Steve';
var lastName = 'Jobs';
var columnOfNamesArr = ['Participants', 'Wozniak, Steve', 'Gates, Bill', 'Cook, Tim', 'Jobs, Mark', 'Jobs, Steve Apple', 'Musk, Elon'];

var res = columnOfNamesArr.reduce((ar, s, i) => {
  if (s.includes(lastName) && s.includes(firstName)) {
    ar.push(i);
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
console.log(res);



Reference:

findIndex()


The modified script is the method I would use but I still get the error. I'm looking at more than one column to see which one contains that combination. So is it possible that it errors out if the column doesn't have that combination of names?

@DanCue Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure which you tested 2 of my proposed scripts from your reply, about The modified script is the method I would use but I still get the error., I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed scripts, no error occurred. For example, when you test "Run code snippet", an error occurs? And, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your current script? By the way, my understanding of your expected result is correct? Can you provide your expected values?

@DanCue About So is it possible that it errors out if the column doesn't have that combination of names?, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and column you expect. Can I ask you about the details of it? By the way, when you use my 1st script, when the searched values are not found, -1 is returned. At my 2nd script, [] is returned. No error occurs for both scripts.

I tested the first one. What happens when you run that one with an array that doesn't have Jobs, Steve Apple?

@DanCue
Thank you for replying. I understood I tested the first one.. About What happens when you run that one with an array that doesn't have Jobs, Steve Apple?, -1 is returned as I have already answered in my comment. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replies, I cannot still imagine your current script for correctly replicating but I still get the error.. In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can you provide your current script? If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

I see what's happening. There is something wrong with the array I have. I'm taking a 2d array and flattening it by using columnOfNamesArr = multipleColumnsArr.map(r => r[3]);. When I write out the array like I have in my post your code works. So this is something else. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer. I have to try and figure out why the mapped/flattened array does not work, though. If you have any insight I would appreciate the help.

@DanCue Thank you for replying. I understand your situation. About the mapped/flattened array does not work, can I ask you about the details of it?

OK. I updated my question to include how I got the array.

@DanCue Thank you for replying. If the column "Participants" is column "A" and you want to use columnArr = namesSht.getRange('A1:A'+ LastRow).getValues();, var columnOfNamesArr = columnArr.map(r => r[1]); should be var columnOfNamesArr = columnArr.map(r => r[0]);. In the case of r[1], the array columnOfNamesArr includes only undefined. I guess that this might be the reason for your new issue.

That was a typo. In my code I had it correct. I made the edit to the post to correct. I'm still getting an error. I really appreciate your help. I must be doing something wrong. I understand if you want to leave it alone at this point. Your answer did help the original question so I thank you very much for that.

I just opened a new question. Hopefully I've explained my issue there well enough. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78986543/resolving-typeerror-when-trying-to-use-findindex

Turns out the error is related to Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get() method. I am loading values 100K rows at a time thanks to your help on previous post and when I use that method it is causing an error but not when I use getValues(). If you have time to view that thread I posted I would appreciate it. I'm at a loss here. Don't know what to do.
