Resolving TypeError when trying to use findIndex
I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
The error occurs at the line var nameIndex = dataFlatArr.findIndex(s => s.includes(lastName) && s.includes(firstName)); in the following script:
  var firstName = 'Steve';
  var lastName = 'Jobs';
  var dataArr =  getValues_({ spreadsheetId: fileID, sheetName: sht.getName(), start: 1, maxRow: lastRow, limit: 100000 });
  var columnsArr = [1,2,3,4];

  for(var i in columnsArr){ 
    if(foundColTrigger == 'No'){
      var dataFlatArr = dataArr.map(r => r[columnsArr[i]-1]);
      //Logger.log(dataFlatArr);
      var nameIndex = dataFlatArr.findIndex(s => s.includes(lastName) && s.includes(firstName));
      Logger.log(nameIndex);
      if(nameIndex != -1){
        foundColTrigger = 'Yes';
        indexColumn = columnsArr[i]-1;
        var fullDisplayName = dataArr[nameIndex][columnsArr[i]-1];
        Logger.log(fullDisplayName)
      }          
    }
  }


Function used to load dataArr:
//getValues in batches of 100K rows
function getValues_({ spreadsheetId, sheetName, start = 1, maxRow, limit = 100000 }) {
  return [...Array(Math.ceil(maxRow / limit))].flatMap((_) => {
    const last = start - 1 + limit;
    const range = `'${sheetName}'!A${start}:${last > maxRow ? maxRow : last}`;
    const temp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range).values;
    start += limit;
    return temp;
  });
}

And here is how my data that goes into dataArr looks:



Participants A
Participants B
Participants C
Participants D




Jackson, Michael
Wozniak, Steve
James, Lebron
Bonds, Barry


Blige, Mary J
Gates, Bill
Jordan, Michael J
McGwire, Mark


Carey, Mariah
Cook, Tim
Curry, Stephen
Sosa, Sammy


Jackson, Janet
Jobs, Mark
Durant, Kevin
Judge, Aaron


Houston, Whitney
Jobs, Steve Apple
Abdul-Jabbar, Kareem
Maris, Roger


Mercury, Freddie
Musk, Elon
Russell, Bill
Ruth, Babe



This scripts runs through each column and checks to see if the firstName and lastName exist in the same cell in one of these columns. If so I return the index of the first instance and then ultimately I grab the full name as displayed by the data. In this case it should be Jobs, Steve Apple. indexColumn would be 1.
When I use getValues() to grab dataArr it works as expected but I want to continue using Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, range).values; method because it is much faster to load. (~30 seconds faster)
Any thoughts on what could be happening? I'm open to alternatives if I can maintain the speed.

Don't add updates. Try to consolidate all the info in the question. More importantly, what's the purpose of showing us the old script with getValues()? Why don't you show the actual script that actually errors out?

ok, I edited it. You're right...I wasn't making things any easier. Let me know if that is better.

From
var dataFlatArr = dataArr.map(r => r[columnsArr[i]-1]);

to
var dataFlatArr = dataArr.map(r => r[columnsArr[i]-1] ?? '');

The above statement uses the nullish coalescing operator (??)...). When r[columnsArr[i]-1] is undefined, the expression returns '' instead of undefined.
Or from
var nameIndex = dataFlatArr.findIndex(s => s.includes(lastName) && s.includes(firstName));

to
var nameIndex = dataFlatArr.findIndex(s => s?.includes(lastName) && s?.includes(firstName));

The above statement uses the optional chaining operator (?.)...). When s is undefined, the expression returns undefined instead of throwing an error.
SpreadsheetApp.Range.getValues returns an empty string for all blank cells, but Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheet, range).values doesn't return values for the blank cells after the last ones with a non-blank value.

That did it. I spent so long trying to figure this out and it seems like such an easy fix. lol I don't think I would have figured that out on my own. Thanks!
